# SSH Client sporadically hangs for few seconds

Tags: ssh, openssl, latency

On Ubuntu 14.04 LTS when I use SSH client, it hangs sporadically for few seconds every minute or so. no input is lost is just delayed.

SSH -V

```
OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
```

.ssh/config

```
Host *
  ServerAliveInterval 240
```

/etc/ssh/ssh_config

```
Host *
SendEnv LANG LC_*
HashKnownHosts yes
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
```

Same machine has Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with the same configuration, works fine. other machine works fine with the same server as well.

SSH -V

```
OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.4, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
```

Comment: Are you using an ADSL or cable connection? If your underlying network connection is a bit flakey you'll see packet loss and retry with pauses like this.

Comment: I tried wireless, wired, work connection, and other networks. same problem.

Comment: Could this be a problem with running out of randomness? Though I'd expect that to cause problems more at connection startup. How big a pool of entropy has the client got - `cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail`

Comment: To clarify - the Ubuntu machine is the SSH client and you're seeing this problem connecting to multiple other systems?

Comment: @PaulHaldane yes. with 12.04 on the same machine I connect to multiple servers without problem. on 14.04 I see this problem with all servers.  entropy is between 770 and 1111 over 60 mins with various activity including ssh ( ssh experienced latency during this time)

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I was having a similar issue and was able to find a resolution at this link:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1022411

Seems like the root issue is a bad driver for the network card. The distributors of the driver have added an easy install script into the download so you can skip step two and run the script in step 3 instead of using the Makefile.